# wordpress permalinks tweeks

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I am getting following permalink structure after creating any post...

http://domain.com/wp/postname

As per Permalink Settings....

Post name:  http://domain.com/wp/sample-post/

This permalink is fine for pages, but how can i add blog as prefix like following....

http://domain.com/wp/**blog**/postname

http://domain.com/wp/**blog**/category/postname

Let me know if you need more information Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Permalink Settings* in admin panel and add "blog" as *Category base* there

Comment: hello it didn't help after entering "blog" in Category base