# Including category-base in a post permalink results in 404

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, 404-error

I have static front-page and separate page `/news/` as the Posts page. I would like to have the single-post URLs like this:

```
www.example.com/news/categoryname/subcategory/postname/
```

and for the category archives:

```
www.example.com/news/categoryname/
```

What I've tried already:

- If I add `news` as my category base and `/news/%category%/%postname%/` as the custom permalink structure, I get the desired URLs but also **404** error for single posts (both with `news/` in URL and without it). All other pages (e.g. category archives, pages etc.) are accessible.
- If I leave category-base empty and permalinks as `/news/%category%/%postname%/`, there are **no 404** errors, but category URLs additionally contain the default `category` slug, like so: `www.example.com/news/category/categoryname/`
- If I use plugins to remove the default category base or just set category base to `.` it's removed together with the `news` part
- If I set permalinks as `/%category%/%postname%/` and add only the category base `news`, there are also **no 404** errors, but links to posts don't start with `news`: `www.example.com/categoryname/subcategory/postname/`

There are some similar unanswered questions: [Posts not showing with custom categorybase and subcategories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/55422/18164) and [wordpress permalinks tweeks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/55324)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I returned to this problem recently and I've found the solution finally! It may or may not work for you - there are two possible cases:

1. If some posts on your site are placed under parent categories and some - in subcategories (child categories), or the categories have different nesting levels (some parent categories have only subcategories while others - sub-subcategories), then **there is no solution**. It's impossible to distinguish `news/category/post-name/` from `news/category/subcategory/` with regex in rewrite rules.
2. If you have fixed nesting level for all categories and post only in the last-level subcategories, then you are in luck! **There is quite simple solution**:

The reason of those 404 pages with `news` both in category base and custom permalink structure is that the category base internal rewrite rule takes the precedence over the permalink structure rules. So `news/category/subcategory/postname/` is interpreted as `index.php?category_name=category/subcategory/postname` and, obviously, WordPress can't find such category, returning 404 page.

What you need to do is to add new rewrite rule on top of the rules list. Place this code in your `functions.php` or wherever you think it's appropriate:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa58471_category_base' );
function wpa58471_category_base() {
    // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
        // The regex to match the incoming URL
        'news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$',
        // The resulting internal URL
        'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]',
        // Add the rule to the top of the rewrite list
        'top' );
}
```

and then update permalink structure from your WordPress General Options page. The code above is for two-level nesting, if you have more or less nested category structure, then edit the regex and resulting URL accordingly.

P.S. thanks to contributors of these useful answers: [help with add_rewrite_rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5478/18164) and [tool to analyze rewrite rules](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3608/18164).

Comment: While there is no solution using regex in rewrite rules, there still is a way to have this functionality: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98083/how-can-you-load-the-categories-page-from-a-hook/98095#98095

Answer (score 6):

You only need to add "/." after category base:

Category base: `news/.` (/. is required as it prevents 404s for post).

This worked perfectly for me :)

EDIT: This field will strip trailing or leading slashes unless you include the "."

Answer (score 0):

Custom permalink structure: `/media/%category%/%postname%/`
Category base: `.`

Worked for me, WordPress 3.4.1, without any related plugins.

Update: Well, later I've noticed that `wp_list_categories` outputs links without "media" in the URL. But posts are accessible with the desired URL structure, and categories archives is in the right place.
Now I'm looking into changing wp_list_categories behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there are 2 problems: I can't access categories archives (both with `media` and without, using the same version 3.4.1), and actual generated links contain `/./` in their addresses.

Comment: That's strange. I guess there maybe 2 reasons:
1. Some of your plugins takes side effects.
2. My WordPress initial setup is somehow different. I'm using http://qwordpress.ru/ with immediate upgrade to current WP version. And in that case the first thing I was working on is the categories structure and URLs, so setup was quite pure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd better post a comment, but I cannot for now. Your code works perfectly, but if you do not want to break the per category RSS feeds it should look like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa58471_category_base' );
function wpa58471_category_base() {
// Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
    // The regex to match the incoming URL
    'news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/][^f][^e][^e][^d]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$', //here my changes to exclude 'feed'
    // The resulting internal URL
    'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]',
    // Add the rule to the top of the rewrite list
    'top' );
}
```

Anyways, thanks for a great code sample. :)