# changin the url (permalink as it goes these days) on one specific menu layer

Tags: menus, permalinks

all the google results and youtube searches did not give me an answer. I hope the WP mothership can.

I am building a small shop (im an artist, few products 3 categories, 1 sublevel)
The shop page (woocommerce) works well but displays all categories.
I want the website to be a portfolio-shop, therefore have the various media I use in the menu itself.

One of the Menu Items is called Portfolio. When clicking, you see 1) drawings 2)oil paintings 3)sculpture.
But each of them has a subcategory.
I made all the products pages, they're fine.
Ex of subcategories: Drawings have 1)graphite, 2)slates and 3) 18+subjects.

QUESTION: how can I make a page or change the general drawings page I made to show only /product-category/graphite? I tried to change the page url itself but it doesn't take the slash / it simply jumps to /product-category-graphite which, will return a 404
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291018/permalinks-for-woocommerce-categories-and-subcategories#answer-291143 - you can add rewrite rules for the subcategories.

Comment: not sure, if rewrite is the right approach. the way i see it, you would have to change the query to exclude some categories, when inside woocommerce product_cat tax query..