# Wordpress Permalink

Tags: permalinks

I need to make my wordpress permalink like the following

Permalink For Category:

```
 www.mydomain.com/category/%category%
```

Permalink For Posts:

```
 www.mydomain.com/category/%category%/article/%postname%
```

Is there any specific code i can use with .htaccess or any plugin that might help

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes and the main issue is..! 1 permalink is working
If i put a special slug for categories the posts does not work..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

Go to your `Settings => Permalinks => Cutom Structure`

And paste this:

```
/category/%category%/article/%postname%/
```

Also paste this on `Category Base` field:

```
category
```

This will work for category but when you visit any post you will be welcomed with `404 page not found` (Isn't it nice?).

So stealing from this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58471/including-category-base-in-a-post-permalink-results-in-404)

Add this code to your themes functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa58471_category_base' );
function wpa58471_category_base() {
    // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
        // The regex to match the incoming URL
        'category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$',
        // The resulting internal URL
        'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]',
        // Add the rule to the top of the rewrite list
        'top' );
}
```

And switch back to `Settings => Permalinks` and click <kbd>Save Changes</kbd>.

Comment: Love you thanks man.. 404 was making my mind blow